# Facebook API: Find User name from User ID

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-apps

I have facebook user id, from this id how can I get user's name?

I tried as

```
    $response = file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId . '?fields=name');
    $user = json_decode($reponse, true);
    print_r($user['name']);
    exit;
```

But it has an error
**file_get_contents(https://graph.facebook.com/"id_of_user"?fields=name): failed to open stream: HTTP request failed! HTTP/1.1 400 Bad Request**

Is there any other way to get user name from user id??

[EDIT]

the user's id I am getting are the generated user id's for my app

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can´t get the username anymore, but i assume you want the real name of the User anyway - which is still possible.

My guess is that your server blocks the request, you should contact your provider. Also, better use [CURL](http://php.net/manual/en/book.curl.php) instead of [file_get_contents](http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php).

Btw, you need to use an Access Token for that call if that is an App Scoped ID - which is most likely the case, because there is no way to get the real/global User ID anymore in an App. More information about Access Tokens:

- https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens
- http://www.devils-heaven.com/facebook-access-tokens/

If you don´t know what App Scoped IDs are, take a look at the changelog: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/changelog

Comment: I am getting response as {
   "error": {
      "message": "Unsupported get request. Please read the Graph API documentation at https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api",
      "type": "GraphMethodException",
      "code": 100
   }
}

Comment: then your call is wrong. what is the exact call? is it a global id or an app scoped one? are you using an access token? which one? user token? app token?

Comment: this is file_get_contents('https://graph.facebook.com/' . $userId . '?fields=name');

Comment: as i said, you need to use an access token and you need to use an app scoped id